# How do I send & receive via RS-232 using Python?

Tags: python

I would like to send but especially receive serial communication using the RS-232 standard. I would like to write a python program to receive data and then write it to files when they come down the line.

How do i write a program in Python to block while waiting for data to arrive instead of spinning in a loop and checking?

Answer (score 6):

Try [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Please refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and refrain from answering questions with a single link and no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html)

Comment: This does not qualify as an answer to the question. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
def read_data():
    data = ser.read(1)
    if data:
        n = ser.inWaiting()
        if n > 0: data += ser.read(n)
        return data

ser = serial.Serial(...)
print read_data()
```

You can experiment with `timeout` param for make the function more efficient.